# Connect IIS on different server

Tags: c#, iis, server

I'm having an IIS on a different machine that I need to connect and I'm not able to do so.
How is it possible to do?

My add pool function:

```
private string addPool(string companyName, string serverName) 
        {
            string errorMsg = string.Empty;
            string result = run_AC("add apppool /name:" + companyName, serverName);
            if (result.EndsWith("added" + Environment.NewLine))
                errorMsg = string.Empty;//"Create application pool ... OK";
            else if (result.StartsWith("ERROR ( message:Failed to add duplicate collection element"))
                errorMsg = "Create application pool ... already exists";
            else
                errorMsg = "Create application pool ... failed - ";

            return errorMsg;
        } 
</code>
<code>
private string siteCreation(string companyName, string BaseSite, string envirementFolderPath, string serverName)
        {
            string errorMsg = string.Empty;
            string result = run_AC("add app /site.name:\"" + BaseSite + "\" /app.name:" + companyName + " /path:/" + companyName + " \"/physicalPath:" + envirementFolderPath + "\" /applicationPool:" + companyName, serverName);
            if (result.EndsWith("added" + Environment.NewLine))
                errorMsg += string.Empty;// "Create app ... OK";
            else if (result.StartsWith("ERROR ( message:Failed to add duplicate collection element"))
                errorMsg += "Create app ... already exists";
            else
                errorMsg += "Create app ... failed - " + result;

            return errorMsg;
        }
```

Comment: What you mean under "Connect"?

Comment: If you want to deploy a website to an remote computer you could use [web deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).

Comment: It is probably a window credential issue.  The two PC must be part of the same group and your user account on both PCs; or you need to have a guest account to connect.

Comment: Your code does nothing to manage IIS. Both MWA and PowerShell remoting can be used, but you used neither.